# web.py / pythonpath confusion

Tags: python, web.py

Im playing around with web.py as a lightweight web framework. Im having problems when i attempt to move the actual implementation of my page into a separate file instead of the root file. As a demonstration, My core.py file looks like this:

```
import web, sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))


urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

ive moved my implementation into a file called index.py at the same level as core.py. My implementation looks like this:

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello world"
```

however, whenever i run my application, i get an error:

`<type 'exceptions.KeyError'> at /`

can anybody tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en#urlhandling, web.py does a lookup for the classes you specified in your urls in the global namespace.

In your core.py there is no class named index (after you moved it), that's what causes this keyerror. In my test I could fix that by importing the index class in core.py.

```
from index import index
```

(I haven't used web.py before, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 3):

You can add dots to crawl into modules.  So say you have a folder controllers with a file named file.py and you wanted to access the controller named index:

```
from controllers import *

urls = (
'/', 'controllers.file.index'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the bug is in your template. I hit this error when if forgot a ':' on an if statement in my template.